# Anorm LIKE clause with String Interpolation

Tags: scala, anorm

Is it possible to use LIKE clause with String Interpolation in Anorm?

```
// e.g. this doesn't work
SQL"SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name LIKE $lastName%".as(userParser.*)
```

**UPDATED**:
I need SQL statement that selects all users with a last name starting with given letters e.g. :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name LIKE 'Smi%';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If expected WHERE clause is something like `WHERE last_name LIKE '%pattern%'` you will have to prepare string before passing it as argument.

```scala
SQL"""SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name LIKE ${"%"+lastName+"%"}""".
  as(userParser.*)
```

Comment: What about SQL Injection? What if lastName is set to a single quote? Will that add a single quote or will it add two single quotes?

Comment: Anorm interpolation, contrary to using `SQL(...)` + standard String interpolation, does exactly the same as using `.on("param" -> paramVal)`, that's to say passing value as JDBC parameter, without SQL injection risk.

Comment: the JDBC placeholder is ?: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html  how is this '%' character used for? is it anorm or jdbc interpreting this char? is there a web page explaining this?

Comment: `%` is inside the param value (inside string), not interpreted in any way either by Anorm or JDBC, just passed to the DB.