# Anorm returning 0 results while psql returns 2 results

Tags: postgresql, scala, anorm

I'm powering a search bar via AJAX that passes a selected filter (radio button) that relates to a database column and a search string for whatever is entered in the search bar. The scala/play/anorm code I am using is this:

```
def searchDB(searchString: String, filter: String): List[DatabaseResult] = {
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  SQL(
    """
      SELECT name, email, emailsecondary, picture, linkedin, title, company, companylink, companydesc, location, github, stackoverflow, twitter, blog
      FROM mailinglistperson
      WHERE {filter} LIKE '%{searchString}%'
    """).on(
          'filter -> filter,
          'searchString -> searchString
    ).as(databaseResultParser.*)
}
```

}

When I run a query on the database (PostgreSQL) using `psql` that is isomorphic to the above anorm code, it returns 2 results, i.e.:

```
select id, name, email from mailinglistperson where company like '%kixer%';
```

But the anorm code returns 0 results when passed the exact same values (I've verified the values via println's)

EDIT: When I switch the anorm code to use String Interpolation I get:

```
[error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Cannot invoke the action
 java.lang.RuntimeException: No parameter value for placeholder: 3
```

EDIT2: I also tried passing the '%...%' along with searchString into LIKE and still got 0 results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anorm LIKE clause with String Interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146075/anorm-like-clause-with-string-interpolation)

Comment: As for the filter value: Have you tried `LIKE {searchString}` together with `searchString = '%...%"` ? That means no single ticks in the SQL command (they should be handled automatically), and to pass the "%" along within `searchString`

Comment: As for the column name: Generally speaking it's not possible to pass in the name of the column using named parameters into SQL. Anorm seems to support it somehow, but the resulting SQL command contains single ticks (because the name is a "string parameter"). So you probably have to embed the column name, like `SQL(s"... where $column like {searchString}` (this is simple String interpolation vulnerable against SQL injection)

Comment: Anorm mixed interpolation `SQL"... WHERE #$column = $searchString"` is not vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: @cchantep I have only commented, that normal string interpolation is vulnerable. Thanks for the hint, I was not aware of mixed interpolation. But a quick test using Play 2.4.0 and 2.5.0 showed that it is vulnerable against SQL injection?!

Comment: For the `#$expressions` you're right, I meant for the `$parameters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues - the name of the column, and the filter value

---

As for the *filter value*: You have to omit the single ticks in the SQL command, and you should pass the placeholder "%" in the argument. The ticks are handled automatically in case of a string.

---

As for the *column name*: It's like a string parameter, so again ticks are handled automatically as well:

> [debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - select ... from ... where 'filter' like '%aaa%'

One solution: Use normal string interpolation `s"""... $filter ..."""`.

---

All together:

```
SQL(
  s"""
    SELECT name, email, ...
    FROM mailinglistperson
    WHERE $filter LIKE {searchString}
  """).on(
      'searchString -> "%" + searchString + "%"
  ).as(databaseResultParser.*)
```

but that should be accompanied by a check before, something like

```
val validColumns = List("name", "email")
if (validColumns.contains(filter)) == false) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("...")
}
```

to guard against SQL injection.

---

**Update**

As pointed out by cchantep: If Anorm >= **2.4** is used, one can use mixed interpolation (both for column names and values):

```
SQL"... WHERE #$filter LIKE $searchString"
```

In this case it's partially safe against SQL injection: that *only* covers the values, and *not* the column name.

**Update 2**

As for logging the SQL statements, see [Where to see the logged sql statements in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9371907)

But as you are using PostgreSQL I suggest the definitive source: The PostgreSQL log: In `postgresql.conf`:

> log_statement = 'all'                   # none, ddl, mod, all

then you will see in the PostgreSQL log file something like this:

> LOG: select * from test50 where name like $1
>
> DETAIL:  Parameter: $1 = '%aaa'

Comment: This worked! It'd be nice if anorm had a way to print the compiled SQL code that gets passed to the database for debugging... does it?

Comment: I have added somemore information on the logging of the SQL commands to the answer.