# Anorm filter a query with LIKE clause

Tags: scala, anorm

Using scala play anorm and mysql, I try to make a sql query, filtering using a LIKE operator:

```
import java.sql.Connection
import anorm._

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()
implicit val conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl)
val list = SQL"select firstName from person where lastName like '%tra%'".as(parser.*)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No parameter value for placeholder: 1
```

here it should filter all persons whose lastName contains the 'tra' string.
why is it not working?
is anorm (or java dbc) treating '%' as a special character? if so, how to escape this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anorm LIKE clause with String Interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146075/anorm-like-clause-with-string-interpolation)

Answer (score 2):

If you expected WHERE clause is something like '%pattern%' you will have to prepare string before passing it as argument.

```
SQL"""SELECT firstName FROM person WHERE lastName LIKE ${"%"+tra+"%"}""".
as(userParser.*)
```

Comment: thx. can you explain this? is '%' a especial character? who is doing that, anorm (i don't think so) or java sql? any reference on this?
is it possible to escape it? i tried escaping it with `LIKE '\\%tra\\%'`, or `LIKE '!%tra!%' ESCAPE '!'`, but didn't work.

Comment: '%' is a wildcard character (in Oracle at least) since. MySQL JDBC driver saves prepared statements on the client side. So using prepared statements with bind variables is much faster because it means that Oracle doesn't have to parse (compile) sql statements again and again.

Comment: the JDBC placeholder is ?: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html
Executing the original query directly on mysql (without JDBC) runs ok.
your example can be simplified as `LIKE ${"%tra%"}`. so, is this % character interpreted by anorm? or by who? i need a reference on this.

Comment: `%` is interpreted by the database.